# Maxing out MongoDB connections

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I have this very specific situation where I need one machine to serve a large number of MongoDB databases (such as 10k+) and every user should be able to connect to it directly.
Our machine is quite powerful and it was running OK for a while, until a few days, when it started causing some problems.

At some point users can't login anymore and I get this from mongoS logs:

```
2016-08-19T18:08:16.667+0000 I NETWORK  [mongosMain] pthread_create failed: errno:11 Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I've tried to change most parameters MongoDB wise and SO wise, but no luck:

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max is 524288
fs.file-max is 128000
kernel.pid_max is 288000
```

/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf has:
    * soft nproc 128000
    * hard nproc 128000

/etc/init/mongos.conf has:

```
limit fsize unlimited unlimited
limit cpu unlimited unlimited
limit as unlimited unlimited
limit nofile 512000 512000
limit rss unlimited unlimited
limit nproc unlimited unlimited
limit memlock unlimited unlimited
```

but still no luck.

Is there any way for me to handle like 100K+ connections?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up with these settings, which appear to solve the problem, though generating a new one: the machine now supports over 100K connections, but it seems eventually it consumes so much RAM that it is not worth it. We ended up adding servers to solve the problem in definitive.

Just in case anyone needs it:

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max is 524288
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established=600
fs.file-max is 524288
kernel.pid_max is 524288
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait=1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=0
vm.max_map_count=524288
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

hi it looks like linux server is running at resources limit.

There is a nice article about linux tuning to accept high number f connection [here](http://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning/)

> Connection Tracking
>
> The next parameter we looked at was Connection Tracking. This is a
>   side effect of using iptables. Since iptables needs to allow two-way
>   communication between established HTTP and ssh connections, it needs
>   to keep track of which connections are established, and it puts these
>   into a connection tracking table. This table grows. And grows. And
>   grows.
>
> You can see the current size of this table using sysctl
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count and its limit using sysctl
>   net.nf_conntrack_max. If count crosses max, your linux system will
>   stop accepting new TCP connections and you’ll never know about this.
>   The only indication that this has happened is a single line hidden
>   somewhere in /var/log/syslog saying that you’re out of connection
>   tracking entries. One line, once, when it first happens.
>
> A better indication is if count is always very close to max. You might
>   think, “Hey, we’ve set max exactly right.”, but you’d be wrong.
>
> What you need to do (or at least that’s what you first think) is to
>   increase max.
>
> Keep in mind though, that the larger this value, the more RAM the
>   kernel will use to keep track of these entries. RAM that could be used
>   by your application.
>
> We started down this path, increasing net.nf_conntrack_max, but soon
>   we were just pushing it up every day. Connections that were getting in
>   there were never getting out.